# Is it possible to print a pdf directly from chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a query to make I have an application that uses JsPDF to make all the impressions. What it does is simple to create a pdf and show it in the Google Chrome preview, then the user chooses the printer and prints perfectly. I want to know if there is any solution to avoid that preview that appears before sending to the printer.

Possible solutions with problems I found:

- Modify the chrome properties by adding "--kiosk-printing". This solution worked but it does not work in all versions.
- Chrome extensions I saw several but none works, I thought about developing it but I don't know if it is possible to get to what I want. If someone knows and can guide me and assures me that I will do it great !.
- CUPS print server, this solution is good because it sends IP to printers but it is impossible for an average user to configure it.

Google Chrome: Version 80.0.3987.149

JsPDF: v 1.5.3

Printer : Epson TM 22 USB

Comment: Extensions can run local native apps via [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativemessaging) (and send data, of course) so you can write such an app e.g. in nodejs or find an existing one.

Comment: Okay, I was reading. Do I need a chrome app or chrome extension? Do you know any example that is similar to what I need?

Comment: Both chrome apps and extensions can use nativeMessaging to communicate with native apps. I'm not aware of an existing example.